# Syntax error in template class with lambda expression

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++-2010, lambda

I have the following simplified scenario:

```
template< typename T>
struct A
{
  A() : action_( [&]( const T& t) { })
  {}

private:
   boost::function< void( const T& )> action_;
};
```

When compiling with Visual C++ 2010, it gives me a syntax error at construction of action_:

```
1>test.cpp(16): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>          test.cpp(23) : see reference to class template instantiation A<T>' being compiled
```

What is strange is that the same example, with no template parameter, compiles just fine:

```
struct A
{
  A() : action_( [&]( const int& t) { })
  {}

private:
  boost::function< void( const int& )> action_;
};
```

I know that one workaround to the problem is to move the action_ initialization in the constructor body, instead of initialization list, like in the code below:

```
template< typename T>
struct A
{
  A()
  {
    action_ = [&]( const T& t) { };
  }

private:
  boost::function< void( const T& )> action_;
};
```

... but I want to avoid such workaround.

Did anybody encountered such situation? Is any explanation/solution to this so called syntax error?

Comment: FWIW, the provided example (after fixing the missing `#include`) compiles without warning with G++ 4.6.1.

Comment: It is specific for Visual C++ 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Broken implementation of lambdas in Visual C++ 2010?  That's my best guess for an explanation.

Although, I'm intrigued what capturing scope variables by reference does in this situtation... Nothing?

Comment: It is a simplified code, to understand the problem. In the real case, I need capturing scope to access some data members (declared, hence initialized prior to the action_ member). I also suspect bad implementation of lambdas...

Comment: `[&]` will capture `this`, and by that means, all member variables (including itself).